# How to read entire worksheet data in excel into DataTable using ClosedXml

Tags: .net, closedxml

Excel Worksheet contains 60K records. Needs to be read and store into DataTable. Currently reading row by row. Is there any other better way using ClosedXml.

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
var wb = new XLWorkbook(fileName, XLEventTracking.Disabled);
using (wb)
{
    var ws = wb.Worksheet(1);
    using (ws)
    {                    
        var headerRow = ws.Row(3);
        int lastColumn = 32;
        foreach (var col in headerRow.Cells(true))
        {
            dt.Columns.Add(col.Value.ToString());
        }
        foreach (var row in ws.Rows().Skip(3))
        {
            var dr = dt.NewRow();
            for (int index = 0; index < lastColumn; index++)
            {
                dr[index] = row.Cell(index + 1).Value;
            }
            dt.Rows.Add(dr);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I could post it as an answer but I feel ashamed because this question is so beat up here on stack overflow. The bottom line is, if you use `Microsoft.Ace.OleDb` provider, you can work with `Excel` just like any Sql Database. You just do, `dataAdapter.Fill(myTable)` and you done. This is good example https://stackoverflow.com/a/7246529/1704458

Answer (score 14):

You could use:

```
using (var wb = new XLWorkbook(fileName, XLEventTracking.Disabled))
{
    var ws = wb.Worksheet(1);
    DataTable dataTable = ws.RangeUsed().AsTable().AsNativeDataTable();
    /* Process data table as you wish */
}
```

Answer (score 4):

The answers above did not work for me due to some exceptions thrown from "AsNativeDataTable();" while reading some cells that have invalid data or some issue.

I could not control nor manage/skip the exceptions thrown and the entire process is stopped.

**The solution is here**

```
public static DataTable ExcelToDatatable_ClosedXML(System.IO.FileStream fileStream, string SheetName)
{
    //Offical way: DataTable dataTable = ws.RangeUsed().AsTable().AsNativeDataTable(); 
    //But cant manage and fix exceptions inside there

    try
    {
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();

        using (XLWorkbook workBook = new XLWorkbook(fileStream))
        {
            //Read the first Sheet from Excel file.
            IXLWorksheet workSheet = workBook.Worksheets.Where(x => x.Name.ToLower() == SheetName.ToLower()).FirstOrDefault();

            //Consider the first row as container column names
            bool firstRow = true;
            foreach (IXLRow row in workSheet.Rows())
            {
                //Use the first row to add columns to DataTable.
                if (firstRow)
                {
                    foreach (IXLCell cell in row.Cells())
                    {
                        dt.Columns.Add(cell.Value.ToString());
                    }
                    firstRow = false;
                }
                else
                {
                    //Add rows to DataTable.
                    dt.Rows.Add();
                    int i = 0;
                    foreach (IXLCell cell in row.Cells())
                    {
                        string val = string.Empty;

                        try
                        {
                            val = cell.Value.ToString();
                        }
                        catch { }

                        dt.Rows[dt.Rows.Count - 1][i] = val;
                        i++;
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        return dt;
    }
    catch
    {
        return null;
    }
}
```

**Usage**

```
string filePath = HostingEnvironment.MapPath("~/Content/Storage/ProductsExcelImports/sample1.xlsx");
System.IO.FileStream fileStream = new System.IO.FileStream(filePath, System.IO.FileMode.Open);
var dt = ExcelToDatatable_ClosedXML(fileStream, "Sheet1");
```

**Thanks**

Answer (score 1):

What Francois suggested is not working for me. I had to do the following:

```
using (var wb = new XLWorkbook(fileName, XLEventTracking.Disabled))
{
    var dt = wb.Worksheet("worksheetName").Table(0).AsNativeDataTable();
    /* Process data table as you wish */
}
```

This is assuming that you only have one table in the worksheet.